# Is there any way to change encoding in a Receive Pipeline in Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk

I have a receive pipeline with only a flat file dissambler in the dissamble stage,
but I need to change the encoding. The incoming file isn't utf-8 but it should be when it comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Tomas Restrepo's Fix Message Encoding Custom Pipeline Component here:

https://github.com/tomasr/fixencoding/tree/master/Winterdom.BizTalk.Samples.FixEncoding

Comment: The answer is an expired Link. Gave it a (Temp) downvote since this is no longer an answer. will change it in an upvote if it gets an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since the incoming file is not UTF-8 and you are using a flatfile disassembler, it means you must have defined a flat file XSD in your project. You use this flat file XSD in your pipeline componet at disassemble stage.

If the above is true, the easiest fix is to use the code page in your flat file schama(XSD) rather than the pipeline component or writing a custom pipeline component just to fix encoding. The screenshot below shows where you can set the source encoding. 
[image]